# Maximum samples and unbounded type length in ROS2 DDS entity

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an extension to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/299297/maximum-limit-of-string-in-ros2/?comment=299320#post-id-299320) question.

I ran a ROS2 demo_py taker and observed the RTI admin console to know more about the data types and QoS.

As you can see in the attached image, it has only one member of type `String` but the max size of the string here is : `2147483647 bytes` which looks a bit strange to me.
Also, if you look at the `Max Samples`, they are also quite big.

Questions :

1. Is this the normal memory allocation of a data type ?
2. How are the maximum samples calculated ? Are these based on the size of the datatype ?
   [image: RTI_AdminConsole]

ps : i know it is not ok to post a picture but i think it gives a much clearer view of the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299322/maximum-samples-and-unbounded-type-length-in-ros2-dds-entity/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RTI is using `RTI_INT32_MAX` as the maximal size for string when support for unbounded string is enabled.
As mentioned in answer from https://answers.ros.org/question/299297/maximum-limit-of-string-in-ros2/ the memory is allocated for 0 elements by default and then reallocated as messages come in. So if you look at your memory usage it should **not** allocate 2GB of RAM to store the string. Similarly, if you look at the packets sent on wireshark or similar tool you will see that only the characters present in the string will be serialized and sent.

The max sample size is provided by the `<TYPE>_Plugin_get_serialized_sample_max_size_ex` Connext generated function.
In this case it always returns: `RTI_CDR_MAX_SERIALIZED_SIZE`.

You can find the connext generated code in your build folder under `<PACKAGE_NAME>/rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp`

For the std_msgs/String message it will be the files:
`rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp/std_msgs/msg/dds_connext/String_Plugin.cxx`
`rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp/std_msgs/msg/dds_connext/String_.cxx`

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
@marguedas : thanks for the explanation.But I still dont get why it allocates such a huge memory for a string ?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-08-01**:
It does **not** allocate that memory for a string.

RTI's definition of an unbounded string is a string that can be "up to" `RTI_INT32_MAX` characters. But the allocated memory is relative to the size of the string that is sent

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
Then what is this memory for and from where is it coming ? I have no clue

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-08-01**:
Can you please provide an example of 2GB of memory being allocated?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
To interface ROS2 and native RTI Connext, the type should be similar, since ROS2 gives me a 2GB string, I need to have the same on the RTI native side as well which creates a problem. That is why in first place my quesion, where does this size come from ? @marguedas

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
then maybe I understood wrong, what does `2147483647` represent here ? Isnt it the size of the string ?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
ahh..ok...so `2147483647` is the max size of `int32` and this is what it represents since RTI interprets unbounded string as max value of Int32 ? Am I right ?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-08-01**:
Yes. RTI interprets an unbounded sting as a string that can have a size between `0` and `RTI_INT32_MAX` (`2147483647`)

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
Now,  get it ! Thank you so much for your patience.
But does that mean, on the native RTI DDS side, i need to give the maxStringLength as `2147483647` so that the type matches on both sides ?